# Mac OS X: Get the size (in pixel) of the dock via Applescript

Tags: applescript, dock

I'm trying to get access to the actual size of the dock in Mac OS X (I'm using Yosemite) via Applescript.
I found some code like [here](http://j4mie.org/blog/how-to-get-the-dimensions-of-the-dock/), which I found in various implementations, but obviously this was for *OS X Leopard*:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    set dock_dimensions to size in list 1
    set dock_width to item 1 of dock_dimensions
    set dock_height to item 2 of dock_dimensions
end tell
```

I also searched in the documentation, whereby I mean the library which is shipped within the script editor of the Mac. The following is copied from there:

```
dock preferences object n : user's dock preferences properties
animate (boolean) : is the animation of opening applications on or off?
autohide (boolean) : is autohiding the dock on or off?
dock size (real) : size/height of the items (between 0.0 (minimum) and 1.0 (maximum))
magnification (boolean) : is magnification on or off?
magnification size (real) : maximum magnification size when magnification is on (between 0.0 (minimum) and 1.0 (maximum))
minimize effect (genie/‌scale) : minimization effect
screen edge (bottom/‌left/‌right) : location on screen
```

As you can see the size is listed, but only as a relative value between 0 and 1.

But I need the size in pixel because I want to resize windows of applications and therefore I need the actual available dimensions in the screen. (It would be sufficient if someone could give me a way to get the maximum and minium size of the dock (which is depending on the display) because then I could calculate the current size.)

I also would like to know if one can get the height of the menubar?

Comment: The first script still works in Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks to @user309603 I did a little more digging and solved the problem (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to AppleScript and didn't read the error message I received (and forgot to post) closely enough, which was:

```
applescript editor is not allowed assistive access
```

So, to get this script to work one has to give the script editor the rights in the security settings of the system preferences.